# Define letter as number, include as part of string for loop

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

```
    If SecretWordLength = 5 Then
        Label3.Visible = True
        Label4.Visible = True
        Label5.Visible = True
        Label6.Visible = True
        Label7.Visible = True
    End If
```

This is the current code for making the dash underneath a letter visible for my hangman game based on the length of the secret word. How can I change this into a FOR loop so that I don't have to repeat this code for every label individually?

I was thinking of using a FOR loop in this way:

```
    For i = 3 To 7
        Labeli.Visible = True
    Next
```

But it does not work as it recognizes the i as the letter itself, not the number I want it to represent. Help please?

Comment: Please add language tag. Possibly VB.Net

Comment: I don't know VB but aren't arrays what you're looking for?

Comment: not exactly, I just need to find a way to change the original code into a loop to make labels visible.

Comment: `Me.Controls("Label" & i.ToString).Visible = True`